automatic zoom launch on Ubuntu
I created an application to automatically launch zoom meeting by clicking on a button, it seems to work on Windows 10, but not on Ubuntu And I'm not sure it works on another machine. I have a list of periodic meetings, the details of which I integrated into a config file, the file contains the names, hours, days, indefinite and password of meetings. I'm trying to call the zoom process and launch the chosen meeting by clicking on a button. It works perfectly on my machine under windows, but nothing happens on my other machine under Ubuntu
I tried this function, which is supposed to be called the zoom process and give it the connection information present in the config file
def lancer_zoom(nom_reunion):
    try:
        with open('config.json', 'r') as fichier:
            donnees = json.load(fichier)
            reunion = donnees.get(nom_reunion)
            if reunion:
                identifiant_reunion = reunion.get('identifiant')
                mot_de_passe_reunion = reunion.get('mot_de_passe')
                if identifiant_reunion and mot_de_passe_reunion:
                    commande_zoom = f'start "" "zoommtg://zoom.us/join?confno={identifiant_reunion}&pwd={mot_de_passe_reunion}"'
                    subprocess.run(commande_zoom, shell=True)
                else:
                    print(f"Informations manquantes pour la réunion {nom_reunion}.")
            else:
                print(f"Réunion {nom_reunion} non trouvée.")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Fichier de configuration introuvable.")


start if for windows. For linux better chance with xdg-open. Use platform module to detect running system.
